# Parameter to QueueUserWorkItem with a lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda, queueuserworkitem

In following code, what does the parameter 's' stand for? Can we not just omit 's' since its not being used in the method, so we have an anonymous method with no parameter like () => ...?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((s)=> 
{
 Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool");
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**

According to the accepted answer, the anonymous method is just a replacement for the normal WaitCallback delegate method like the one in ocd below, that is needed by QueueUserWorkItem as a parameter to it.  Therefore, 's' should be of object type, since its a parameter to the ThreadProc method.

```
void ThreadProc(Object stateInfo) {
   // No state object was passed to QueueUserWorkItem, so  
   // stateInfo is null.
    Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool");
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# 2.0 syntax for anonymous delegates allows omitting the parameter list, in which case it will match any set of (non-`ref` non-`out`) parameters and ignore them.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate {
   Console.WriteLine("Working on a thread from threadpool");
});
```

Note that `delegate {}` is different from `delegate () {}`

The lambda syntax, on the other hand, doesn't work without a parameter list provided.

Comment: When I check if 's' is null within the anonymous method, it is null. So its confusing why 's' is needed?

Comment: @Sunil: It is needed because it is part of the `System.Threading.WaitCallback` type.

Comment: I can run a Task like this: Task.Run (()=> { DoThis();}), which allows a method without any parameters. Sorry its not making sense.

Comment: So its  the parameter of WaitCallback type that is normally passed to QueueUserWorkItem method?

Comment: Yes, `QueueUserWorkItem` requires a `WaitCallback` delegate.  So the lambda or anonymous delegate has to be compatible with it.  And `WaitCallback` has one parameter.

Comment: Ok. Get it now. Thanks.

Comment: And the parameter to Waitcallback is of 'object' type, so 's' is for that object type parameter. Get it now.